# Prove that an equation has only one complex solution

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I need to prove that the equation $z - \varepsilon \sin z = a$ has only one solution for small $\varepsilon$. The problem doesn't state anything specifically but I assume that $a$ is an arbitrary complex number.

I've tried using Rouche's theorem on circles with arbitrarily large diameters and with center in the origin of the coordinate system where I take $z - a$ as the dominating function and $\varepsilon \sin z$ as the smaller function, but I achieved no success. I would be very happy if someone could help me with this task.

Comment: the statement of the problem is unclear as if one fixes any $c \ne 0$ the equation $z-c\sin z=a$ has infinitely many solutions; maybe one wants to prove that for small $\epsilon$ there is only one solution close to $a$ (in some sense to be specified) but as stated the problem is either incorrect or incomplete

Comment: @Conrad I just translated the problem, there is no additional information given besides what I've written. How do you know that there are infinitely many solutions? Does it follow from the Great Picard theorem because sine has an essential singularity at infinity?

Comment: Where is that problem coming from? Perhaps some context is needed here.

Comment: @KBS No there is no context. It's from a Slovenian problem book for complex analysis. The task is separated from all other problems, it is not a subproblem. The literal translation of the problem is following: "Find the number of roots of the equation $z - \varepsilon \sin z = a$ for small $\varepsilon$." And the solution in the book is 1.

Comment: One can use Picard but also the fact that $\sin$ is entire order $1$ and then the only way the equation has finite solutions is you can write $z-c\sin z-a=P(z)e^{az+b},  P$ polynomial  and it's easy to get a contradiction then (this uses just Jensen, not Picard so is "elementary")

Comment: @Conrad To be honest we didn't mention anything about the order of entire functions in lectures so sadly I don't understand your alternative proof, but you helped me a lot by saying that the problem is incorrect and by confirming that I can use Picard! I would accept your answer if I could do so in the comments.

Comment: The proof is very simple since if an entire function $f$ has finitely many zeroes then factoring those by a polynomial one gets that $f=Pe^g$ for some entire $g$ Jensen theorem relates $g$ with $f$ though here one can easily see directly that $g$ must be linear by taking limits at infinity and then get a contradiction by taking limits through various half lines (positive reals, $ai$ etc)

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy to be of help - note that for real values and real solutions, the equation above has only one solution since the derivative (on the real line) is positive for all $\epsilon <1$ etc